# Get username/account name from email address

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Client table contains first name, last name, email, and department.  I need to compare the username portion of the email address (that is, everything before @) to the session's username to verify authenticity.

How may I structure my cfquery to compare the desire portion of the email address to the session variable casuser?

```
<cfquery name="getUsername" dsn="myDSN">    
select firstname, lastname, email, department, organization, rank
            from client
            where email= '#casuser#'
</cfquery>
```

The database is on SQL Server 2008 using CF8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much you need to use like statement and compare anything including @ sign. So should be something similar to this:

```
select firstname, lastname, email, department, organization, rank             
from client             
where email like '#casuser#@%'
```

Comment: Don't forget to use <cfqueryparam>.  keep that stuff secure

Comment: cfqueryparam will also ensure your SQL Server caches the query plan. Easily earned performance gains FTW!

Answer (score 1):

There's obviously nothing wrong with Andrey's approach, but in the event you'd rather not use the *like*...

```
email = getToken(casUser,1,"@");
```

Definitely include cfqueryparam

Comment: I believe `casUser` only contains a name, not an email address. So in this case `LIKE` is required.

Comment: So it would need to be the other way round: WHERE getToken(email,1,'@') = '#casuser#'

Comment: No, you cannot use CF functions on a database column. It would need to be a database string function. But in this case I probably would not bother. May as well just use `LIKE` ;)

Comment: @Leigh Sorry, I misread the question. I agree, a udf would be overkill on something that could be easily handled by the `LIKE`.

Comment: @nykash - Yep. But if it were the reverse (matching email variable against name column) that would definitely be the right approach.